# How to make the value in data store memory global

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulink model that generates signals, I want to store the signal using data store write and data store memory (those are linked together), then I want to be able to use the stored signal (an array) as a global variable in MATLAB.

When I try to make the variable global in matlab nothing happens. Even after I start the simulation

```
global Signal_full_og; %the variable I want to make global
sig_arr = [];
sim simF.slx     %simulation file 
for vref= 0:1:10  %1st 10 signals
      sig_arr(index, :) = Signal_full_og;
end
```

Below there is a picture of the Data Store Write and Data Store Memory from my Simulink model

[image: Data Store Write and Data Store Memory]

And below there is a picture of the block parameters of Data Store Memory
[image: Data Store Memory block parameters]

I have tried to follow the documentation from Mathworks and still I can't get a global variable. Does anyone spot any mistakes in this way or is there a better way to do the same thing?

Comment: Do you actually need it to have global scope? Looks like you could just be using a `To Workspace` block in this example

Comment: @Wolfie  actually I need it to have a global scope because I wanna generate different signals (the code is more complicated for that, the for loop up there is just a simplified version). The problem is that it doesn't appear to be global even I declare it on the code and added the correct blocks on simulink. Would `To Workspace` be able to store a different signal (an array) each run of the iteration?

Comment: Looks like you're running programmatically anyway, you could use `To Workspace` to put the output into a scalar variable and assign that variable into your array after the `sim` is finished each iteration